# How to use Bull, Throng, and Redis with Discord.js

Tags: node.js, heroku, discord.js, bull

I want to run long "scraping" processes on heroku server using discord as my front interface.
I created a discord bot that runs the scraping when a command is used. all is working well.
However, I want to use a queue system so that multiple users or even bulk usage will be possible.

Reading through [heroku docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/node-redis-workers), I'm trying to add Bull to handle the queue system along with redis and throng.
I got everything done and installed on my local machine for testing.
I have the index file that listens to the discord command and fires off a job.
and a worker file that handles the queue and the cluster using throng.
Kicking off the job works fine. but the issue is how can i run the worker file! which will run the function that will execute the actual heavy work.

So, this is what I have tried so far. in my index file I listen to the discord command, add a new job to the queue, and reply to the user, last part is where I get the returned value when the job is done.

```
client.on('interactionCreate', async interaction => {
    if (!interaction.isChatInputCommand()) return
    const {commandName, options} = interaction
    if (commandName === 'views') {
        await workQueue.add('process', {text: 'Running...'})
        await interaction.reply(`processing... the results will be posted when done`)
    }
})
workQueue.on('global:completed', async (jobId, result) => {
    console.log(`Job completed with result ${result}`)
})
```

This is my worker file, where I create the start function as an entry point for throng *following the docs.
I haven't added the actual heavy work method yet. so I'm just logging in and returning the job ID.

```
const throng = require('throng')
const Queue = require("bull")

const REDIS_URL = process.env.REDIS_URL || "redis://127.0.0.1:6379"
const workers = process.env.WEB_CONCURRENCY || 1
const maxJobsPerWorker = 50


function start() {
    // Connect to the named work queue
    const workQueue = new Queue('work', REDIS_URL)

    workQueue.process(maxJobsPerWorker, async job => {
        console.log("Im here")
        return {value: job.id}
    })
}

throng({workers, start})
```

How can I have the start function and get the returned value back so that I can send it back to the user?
This is still a new concept to me, this might not be the right way to do it. so please feel free to correct me and guide me.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you initialize your worker function inside your `Procfile` when you deploy to Heroku. So your `Procfile` may look something like:

```
web: node index.js
worker: node worker.js
```

To deploy, you will have to install [node-foreman](https://www.npmjs.com/package/foreman) which handles your `Procfile` and update the `start` script in `package.json` file as follows:

`start: nf start`